# What is the relationship between Sesame & Alibaba?

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, federated

I am a beginner in this & I am having a hard time understanding this.

What is Alibaba and Sesame?

In the above two, which one does the query optimization and which one does the part of creating repositories.

Any kind of input will be fine. Thanks.

Comment: @cygri I would really appreciate if you could answer this question. My question is not a troll and I really need help for this.

Comment: I know. Sorry. I don't know the answer I'm afraid. :-(

Comment: What have you read so far? See at least [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesame_(framework)) and [this one](http://notes.3kbo.com/sesame).

Comment: If you are interested in federated queries, consider SPARQL 1.1 SERVICE keywork (documentation here: http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-federated-query/).

Apache Jena supports SPARQL 1.1, including SERVICE and you can quickly install your SPARQL endpoints using Apache Jena's Fuseki server: http://incubator.apache.org/jena/documentation/serving_data/

Answer (score 3):

> "AliBaba is a RESTful subject-oriented client/server library for distributed persistence of files and data using RDF metadata. AliBaba is the beta version of the next generation of the Elmo codebase. It is a collection of modules that provide simplified RDF store abstractions to accelerate development and facilitate application maintenance."

- http://www.openrdf.org/alibaba.jsp

> "Sesame is a de-facto standard framework for processing RDF data. This includes parsing, storing, inferencing and querying of/over such data. It offers an easy-to-use API that can be connected to all leading RDF storage solutions."

- http://www.openrdf.org/about.jsp

I imagine the query engine, query optimization and storage are part of Sesame, not Alibaba. Alibaba is application code which sits on top of Sesame.

There are also alternatives in Java, such as Apache Jena:

- http://incubator.apache.org/jena/

Guess what I use? ;-)

Comment: Re: "a de-facto standard framework" ... that's just marketing, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: I'd say Jena is certainly an alternative to Sesame, but not Alibaba.  I think the closest equivalent for Jena is perhaps JenaBeans, though that might be defunct.  Jastor also comes to mind.